# How Would I Resolve This Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

A simplified version of my table:

```
 -------------------------------------------
| sender | recipient | date       | amount  |
 -------------------------------------------
| A      | B         | 2016-01-01 | 500.00  |
| C      | B         | 2016-01-02 | 600.00  |
| D      | C         | 2016-01-03 | 1025.00 |
| D      | D         | 2016-01-04 | 300.00  |
| D      | D         | 2016-01-05 | 300.00  |
| D      | D         | 2016-01-06 | 300.00  |
| D      | D         | 2016-01-07 | 300.00  |
| D      | D         | 2016-01-08 | 300.00  |
 -------------------------------------------
```

How can I get a `recipient` who has 3 `OR LESS` rows summing a minimum `amount` of `1024.00` or more?

It will not take `D` because it doesn't has 3 rows with more than an `amount` of `1024.00`.

Expected Result:

```
 -----------
| recipient |
 -----------
| B         |
| C         |
 -----------
```

Comment: Use group by, sum(), and filter in having

Comment: Can you show me the example? But has to have 3 rows summing 1024...

Comment: By looking your expected result it looks like you're looking for recipient with **less** than three rows and amount >= 1024...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.  The key observation is that the sum of the three highest values is going to exceed 1024, if any 3 do.

In MySQL, you can do this using variables:

```
select recipient, sum(amount) as amount_3
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@r = recipient, @rn + 1,
                        if(@r := recipient, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @r := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by recipient, amount desc
     ) t
where rn <= 3
group by recipient
having sum(amount) >= 1024;
```

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple query:

```
select recipient
from table
group by recipient
having count(*) <= 3 and sum(amount) >= 1024
```

Comment: I got empty result...

select recipient
from transfers
group by recipient
having count(*) >= 3 and sum(amount) >= 1024;

Comment: And count(*)  >= 3 it will take D and it should because I want that only 3 rows (imagine it has 100) is bigger than 1024.

Comment: Maybe my explanation has not well done...  It doesn't need to be 3 it can be 1 with 1024 or 2 summing more than 1024 as a maximum of 3 rows...

Comment: I need to get recipient who has 3 OR LESS rows summing a minimum of 1024 or more.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct recipient
from tablename t1
where 1024 <= (select sum(amount)
               from (select amount
                     from tablename t2
                     where t2.recipient = t1.recipient
                     order by amount desc
                     limit 3) dt1
              ) dt2
```

Comment: getting an error saying `Every derived table must have its own alias` could you please help

Comment: @PrakashPalnati, ask a new question.

Comment: @PrakashPalnati, I always forget about that silly restriction... (ANSI SQL has no such requirement.)